# WPF Active Directory Calls performance issues

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, optimization, active-directory

I have a C# WPF applicaiton that I am trying to perform a light check with the Active Directory Server and am running into serious performance issues of 20-30 seconds for the funciton to run. Using the identical code, I can place it in a Winforms application and it takes about 1 second or less. Since it is a big AD, I am guessing it is pulling all properties for the end user, but I really only want the first and last name of the person (for other purposes), and to ensure the user is in Active Directory.

Here is the code:

```
public string DomainUserNameGet(string ActiveDirectoryServer, string WindowsUserID) {
    /// queries AD to get logged on user's name
    string results = "";
    try {
    // create your domain context
    PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(
        ContextType.Domain
        , ActiveDirectoryServer
    );
    UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(
          oPrincipalContext
        , IdentityType.SamAccountName
        , ActiveDirectoryServer + @"\" + WindowsUserID                    
    );
    results =
        oUserPrincipal.GivenName.ToString()
        + " "
        + oUserPrincipal.Surname.ToString();
    } catch { }
    return results;
}
```

The crazy thing is I can do the following via command line and get the response in about 1 second:

```
NET USER /DOMAIN LANID | find "LANID" /c
```

Any ideas on how I can improve performance?

Comment: why are you creating the principal context every time, surely it can be cached?

Comment: I can't imagine that WPF vs. WinForms can have anything to do with it. There must be something else that is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RenniePet had it right; Turns out there was a DNS issue; I am unsure why this showed up in WPF vs. win forms though.